# Proxy Model no non-abstract model base class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am upgrading from **Django==1.7.8** to **Django==1.8.2** and am running into this issue that prevents me from even creating a new migration to suppress it.

I have a set up that looks like this

from a separate package I have the following

```
class Category(MyModel, Mixin):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

and in my django app I have the following

```
from mypackage.myapp.models import Category

class Section(Category):

    class Meta(Category.Meta):
        proxy = True
```

When I upgrade to `Django==1.8.2` I receive the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
     utility.execute()
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
     super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
     super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
     failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
     old_config = self.setup_databases()
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
     **kwargs
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
     serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
     test_flush=not keepdb,
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
     return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
     executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 104, in migrate
     state = migration.mutate_state(state, preserve=do_run)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 83, in mutate_state
     operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 53, in state_forwards
     list(self.managers),
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 81, in add_model
     self.reload_model(app_label, model_name)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 152, in reload_model
     self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 262, in render_multiple
     model.render(self)
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 546, in render
     body,
   File "/var/venvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 216, in __new__
     raise TypeError("Proxy model '%s' has no non-abstract model base class." % name)
 TypeError: Proxy model 'Section' has no non-abstract model base class.
```

I'm a little confused as when I access the parents attribute of the Proxy Model it has the appropriate `Category` model and `Category._meta.abstract` returns `False`. I stepped into the stack where the error is occurring and when it is evaluating my `Section` model as a proxy with baseclass `Category`, it passes, but it goes on to test it with `ModelBase` where it fails

Comment: If you remove the `(Category.Meta)` from the `class Meta:` what happens?

Comment: Tried that. nothing.

Comment: It is like you have only abstract models. Are your mixin and MyModel abstract? If so try also inheriting from models.Model

Comment: `MyModel` & `Mixin` are both abstract, but the `Category` object is not. I have tried adding a proxy with a similar configuration to a project that was already on `Django==1.8.2` and am only running into the issue when upgrading.

Comment: If MyModel and Mixin are abstract then based on your code above you aren't inheriting from a base model that isn't abstract so you need to inherit from. models.Model. Or at least that is how I am reading things, I could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding inheritance, but it is the Proxy Model `Section` that is inheriting from the Concrete Model `Category`. The following returns what I believe to be expected behavior for a typical Concrete/Proxy inheritance. `Section._meta.concrete_model` returns `mypackage.myapp.models.Category`

Comment: Does `manage.py check` return any errors? If not, it's probably a problem that only exists in your migrations. You'll have to change your existing migrations until there is never a situation where your proxy model inherits from a non-concrete model.

Comment: I have spent the last half hour playing with code trying to reproduce something like this, and can't seem to. Sorry. Not sure I can help any on this.